# crash when loading the View

Tags: ios, uislider

I have a button named **settings**, when I press this button the application crashes.

I have doubt in warnings that's why I'm going to show you what I got when building:

```
 .../RechercherViewController.m:66: warning: 'UISlider' may not respond to '-setShowValue:'
```

that warning is pointing me at this line in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[rayonDeRechercheSlider setShowValue:YES];
```

`rayonDeRechercheSlider` is a UISlider declared in the `.h` file of the View :

```
IBOutlet UISlider *rayonDeRechercheSlider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISlider` does not use a boolean property called `showValue` and also UISlider does not offer any explicit method called `setShowValue:`, hence the method call: `setShowValue:YES` on a `UISlider` will crash the app.

You may want to call `[rayonDeRechercheSlider setValue:1.0 animated:YES]` (replace 1.0 with the value you intend to set.

Comment: Beat me to it... Malek please read the class reference. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi, thx it works, but i want to ask you what the setValue:1.0 suppose to do, my slider have the interval from 1 to 70..thx

Comment: 1.0 was just a placeholder. Replace it with 35.0f then, for the fun of it :D -- the value of a slider is a float, hence I am adding that ".0f" to make it clear to the compiler that I want to feed in a static constant float value. Just syntactic sugar...

Answer (score 0):

After a little further research of where you might have gotten the idea of `setShowValue:` being a valid selector. I ran across this custom class called [`UISliderControl`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UISliderControl)

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

EDIT:

[More Info](http://www.onedollarapp.com/?p=46)